# What is a "complete unit of execution" in Java?

Tags: java

IMO a statement was something you can write until the first semi-colon `;` in a single line.

And for me this was a statement:

```
List<String> list = Pattern.compile("#").splitAsStream("Hello#how#are#you")
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But now I'm in doubt, maybe I should reconsider my idea of statement. Trying to understand what exactly a statement is, I found this in the Java Documentation - [Expressions, Statements, and Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) (maybe I've already read it... twenty years ago or more)

> Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A
>   statement forms a complete unit of execution. The following types of
>   expressions can be made into a statement by terminating the expression
>   with a semicolon (;).
>
> - Assignment expressions
> - Any use of ++ or --
> - Method invocations
> - Object creation expressions

So what is a "complete unit of execution" in Java?

How should my example be considered, a multiple statement? And how many statements? If you count each method invocation and the assignment expression I see 5 statements.

Comment: It is a statement. The quote doesn't say that a statement can't contain multiple method invocations. It says that a method invocation can be made into a statement by adding a semicolon.

Comment: @khelwood So, just to be clear, do you think that my example can be considered a single statement?

Comment: Yes. It is a single statement that contains multiple method invocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a single *declaration statement*. It consists of a single declaration, and a single initialization expression, no matter how complex:

```
List<String> list = Pattern.compile("#").splitAsStream("Hello#how#are#you").collect(Collectors.toList());
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  Declaration                  Initialization expression (very long)
```

Similarly, a single expression is a single statement, no matter how complex:

```
matcher = Pattern.compile("#").matcher("Hello#how#are#you");
```

Multiple method invocations that you "chain" are considered a single statment.

Answer (score 3):

From the [JLS - Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html)

**Chapter 14. Blocks and Statements**

> Some statements contain other statements as part of their structure;
>   such other statements are substatements of the statement. We say that
>   statement S immediately contains statement U if there is no statement
>   T different from S and U such that S contains T and T contains U. In
>   the same manner, some statements contain expressions (§15) as part of
>   their structure.

**In brief, a statement may be composed of substatements or of expressions.**

Here you are in the multiple expressions case :

So this :

```
List<String> list = Pattern.compile("#").splitAsStream("Hello#how#are#you")
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

is a statement composed of 4 [method invocation expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) :

```
Pattern.compile("#")

splitAsStream("Hello#how#are#you")

.collect()

Collectors.toList()
```

Suppose this code is put in a method :

```
void m(){
    List<String> list = Pattern.compile("#").splitAsStream("Hello#how#are#you")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Look at the disassembly version of the compiled code :

```
 void m();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #15                 // String #
       2: invokestatic  #17                 // Method java/util/regex/Pattern.compile:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/regex/Pattern;
       5: ldc           #23                 // String Hello#how#are#you
       7: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/util/regex/Pattern.splitAsStream:(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
      10: invokestatic  #29                 // Method java/util/stream/Collectors.toList:()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
      13: invokeinterface #35,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/stream/Stream.collect:(Ljava/util/stream/Collector;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      18: checkcast     #41                 // class java/util/List
      21: astore_1
      22: return
}
```

Each one of these sub statements results to a distinct invocation but the result of the chaining of them is storing in a single variable as this is a single statement :

```
   21: astore_1
```